# Why hasManyThrough from Eloquent documentation not work?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent

Example from the documentation "To many through" can't run
Where is the error here?

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

**Model Country**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
      'id',  'name',
    ];
    //server error
   return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post', 'App\User',
           'country_id', 'user_id', 'id'

);

}
```

**Model User**
there are other columns in the table, but they are not used in this example

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'id',  'country_id', 'name'
    ];   

}
```

**Model Post**

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
      'id',  'user_id', 'title',
    ];

}
```

**Resource Country**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Country extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return parent::toArray($request);

return [
      'id' => $this->id,
      'name' => $this->name,
      'title' => $this->title,

       ];

   }
}
```

**Controller Country**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Country;
use App\Http\Resources\Country as CountryResource;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
public function index()
       {

    $countries = Country::with(['post'])->get();
    return CountryResource::collection($countries);
      }
}
```

the router is configured correctly-checked

Task: show three columns in the table 
id (country) name (country) title (posts)-all for each country

the manual describes something crumpled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are passing through foreign keys and column names to the hasManyThrough method, you must specify *both* foreign keys and *both* local keys. From the Laravel docs:

```
return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post',
            'App\User',
            'country_id', // Foreign key on users table...
            'user_id', // Foreign key on posts table...
            'id', // Local key on countries table...
            'id' // Local key on users table...
        );
```

Your method only has 'id' once.

Also, this logic should be inside a function called posts() on the Country model. For example:

Country.php

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
      'id',  'name',
    ];
    public function posts() {
           return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Post', 'App\User',
           'country_id', 'user_id', 'id', 'id');
    }



}
```

Then in your Country Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;
use App\Country;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
public function index()
       {

    $countries = Country::with('posts')->get();
    return $countries->toJson();
      }
}
```

I would get rid of the CountryResource thing. All it's doing (i think) is converting the data to json, which you can do with the built in toJson() method. If you don't want all columns being returned (for example, maybe you dont want the timestamps showing), you can edit Country.php or Post.php and add `protected $hidden = ['created_at','updated_at']` etc. at the top.

Comment: `return CountryResource::collection(Country::all());` - without errors but `title` not show. And `$country = Country::with('posts')->get();
      return CountryResource::collection($country);` - server error

Comment: Not sure what the line `return CountryResource::collection($country)` is adding. Would `return $country` not return the collection from the line above?

Comment: I didn't understand how to write the controller correctly. Could you write the controller code completely?

Comment: class User extends Authenticatable change to Model